# gulp.watch doesn't catch a new files

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gulp

I have the following gulpfile

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var clean = require('gulp-clean');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var coffee = require('gulp-coffee');
var cache = require('gulp-cached');
var path = require('path');

var dist = './Test/public/';
var assets = './Test/assets/';

var paths = {
    coffee: ['./**/*.coffee']
};

var coffeeTask = function () {
        console.log('coffeeTask');
        return gulp.src(paths.coffee, { cwd: assets + '**' })
            .pipe(cache('coffee'))
            .pipe(coffee({ bare: true }))
            .pipe(rename({
                extname: ".coffee.js"
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(dist));
};

gulp.task('clean', function() {
    return gulp.src(dist)
        .pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task('coffee', ['clean'], coffeeTask);
gulp.task('coffee-watch', coffeeTask);

gulp.task('build', ['clean', 'coffee']);

gulp.task('watch', ['build'], function() {
    var w = gulp.watch(paths.coffee, ['coffee-watch']);
    w.on('change', function(evt) {
        console.log(evt);
    });
});

gulp.task('default', ['build']);
```

The key point of this configuration is use the same tasks for deploy and watch processes (read "build" and "watch" tasks).

The problem is that watch task doesn't catche any new coffee files. Edited or removed coffee files are processed well. According the following [issue](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/675) it should works. What the reason is?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using gulp-watch module:

```
watch(paths.coffee, function(evt) {
    gulp.start('coffee-watch');
});
```

The question no is how to remove in dist folder deleted file in assets folder?